# RequireJs - Nested require JS File

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

I have 4 script file.

1. script.js -> main script file
2. testApp.js
3. addition.js
4. multiplication.js

script.js requires testApp.js and testApp.js require addition.js and multiplication.js.
I need the output of calculate function which is in script.js

Error - add() is not defined.

My Code -

### Script.js

```
require(["testApp"],function(){
    alert("hello Script");
    alert(calculate());
});
```

### testApp.js

```
define(["addition","multiplication"], function calculate(){ 
    alert("hello testApp");
    var c;
    var a=5;
    var b=10;
    c = add(a,b)+mul(a,b);
    return c;
});
```

### addition.js

```
define(function add(a,b){
    alert("hello Addition");
    return a+b;
});
```

### multiplication.js

```
define(function mul(a,b){
    alert("hello Multiplication");
    return a*b;
});
```

Comment: Have you given the right paths for all the js files in your config?

Comment: all are in same folder.. alerts are working..

Comment: Did my solution worked?

Answer (score 0):

I tried this way in local and it works:

**testApp.js**

```
define(["addition","multiplication"], function(addition, multiplication){ 
  alert("in testApp");
  return {
    calculate :function(){
        alert("hello testApp");
        var c;
        var a=5;
        var b=10;
        return addition.add(a,b)+ multiplication.mul(a,b);
     }
 } 
});
```

**addition.js**

```
 define([], function(){
    return {
     add: function(a,b){
      alert("hello Addition");
      return a+b;
     }
   }
});
```

**multiplication.js**

```
 define([], function(){
    return {
     mul: function(a,b){
      alert("hello Multiplication");
      return a*b;
     }
   }
});
```

and finally in your code:

```
   require(["testApp"],function(testApp){
     alert("hello main script");
     alert(testApp.calculate());
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

**addition.js**

```
function add(a,b){
    alert("hello Addition");
    return a+b;
}
```

**multiplication.js**

```
function mul(a,b){
    alert("hello Multiplication");
    return a*b;
}
```

**testApp.js**

```
function calculate(){ 
    alert("hello testApp");
    var c;
    var a=5;
    var b=10;
    c = add(a,b)+mul(a,b);
    return c;
}
```

and finally **Script.js**

```
requirejs.config({
    shim: {
        'testApp': ['addition','multiplication'],
    }
});
require(["testApp"], function () {
    alert("hello Script");
    alert(calculate());
});
```

define the dependency using shim in requireJS